# Split data in sql with multiple delimiters ( , and - ) with owns rule

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, numbers

I have data like this `1,2,3,4-8,10,11`

I want split the data into rows with these 2 rules :

1. The `,` will only split the data into rows. Ex 1,2,3 become :

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   ```
2. The `-` will split into series number. Ex 4-8 become :

   ```
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   ```

How can a SQL query do that? Please answer and keep it simple.

Comment: It will be way easier and most probably more performant to do this on application level. And the best would be to **NOT** store comma separated values in one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work as long as your intervals are less than 2048 (let me know if that numbers can go higher) and you @data follow your current syntax:

```
declare @data varchar(50) = '1,2,3,4-8,10,11'

;with x as
(
     SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') subrow
     FROM (
         SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
               REPLACE(@data, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
     ) a
     CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
), y as
(
SELECT 
CAST(coalesce(PARSENAME(REPLACE(subrow, '-', '.'), 2),
              PARSENAME(REPLACE(subrow, '-', '.'), 1)) as int) f,
CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(subrow, '-', '.'), 1) as int) t from x
)
select z.number from y
cross apply 
(select y.f + number number
from master..spt_values
where number <= y.t - y.f and type = 'p'
) z
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11
```

Comment: Nice.  Though what about the table spt_values?  Not seen this before.

Comment: @ScubaManDan it is a build in table in sqlserver

Comment: :)  I guessed.  I was just wondering what it's used for though.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk How to implement that function if the data in a table? I have ProjectID and PONumber (the PONumber data look like my question). I want to split the PONumber with each of ProjectId.

Comment: @kelly you create a function that returns a tabel and takes a varchar(x) as parameter

Comment: @Kelly PS: to join the function you need cross apply

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MultipleDelemiterSplit
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delemiter1 Varchar(100),
   @Delemiter2 Varchar(100)
)
RETURNS  TABLE
AS

   RETURN
   ( 
      SELECT Item = FirstSet.cnt.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM
      (
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<cnt>'
          + REPLACE(REPLACE(@List, ISNULL(@Delemiter1,''), '</cnt><cnt>') , ISNULL(@Delemiter2,''), '</cnt><cnt>')
          + '</cnt>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('cnt') AS FirstSet(cnt)
   );

GO 

Select * From dbo.MultipleDelemiterSplit ('10:0,11:1,12:3,13:4,15:5,16:6',',',':')
```

Comment: What If I want the values in two columns like                                                   item     item2                                                                                                                           10           0                                                                                                   11           1                                                                                                   12           3

Answer (score 1):

I just created a sample for two delimiters, need to do something for generic

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Separator1 Varchar(100),
   @Separator2 Varchar(100)
)
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS

   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(REPLACE(@List, ISNULL(@Separator1,''), '</i><i>') , ISNULL(@Separator2,''), '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );

GO  

Select * From dbo.SplitStrings ('1,2,3,4 5,6,7',',','-')
```

Just Pass null or empty if second separator is not required

Comment: I tested this and didnt get the requested result

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question you could use a recursive CTE:

```
select '1,2,3,4-8,10,11' as value into #testtab

with tst(DelimValue,Value) as
(
    select cast(LEFT(value,charindex(',',value+',')-1) as varchar(50)),stuff(value,1,charindex(',',value+','),'') 
    from #testtab
     union all
    select cast(LEFT(value,charindex(',',value+',')-1) as varchar(50)),stuff(value,1,charindex(',',value+','),'')
    from tst
    where value > ''
)
select DelimValue 
from tst
```

This will give you the results:

```
1
2
3
4-8
10
11
```

To give credit where it is due, I learned this from here: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows).

Now for the ranges, I would imagine you could write a procedure with a loop that will find the first integer before the dash as the start, and the second integer as the end, and then insert / return rows for that range. Though I imagine there must be a smarter way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later;

example

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE('1,2,3,4-8,10,11', '-', ','), ',')
```

result

```
value
-----------
1
2
3
4
8
10
11
```

Syntax

```
STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator [ , enable_ordinal ] )
```

documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question correctly - you have't accounted for 4-8 being split to 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.