# SQL Splitting strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following two strings in a table:

```
CN=ABCDEFG,OU=7SOE,OU=TEMP,OU=Sydney,OU=Australia,DC=LDAP,DC=COM
CN=ABCDEFGHIJ,OU=7SOEFHU,OU=TEST,OU=TEMP,OU=London,OU=Europe,DC=LDAP,DC=COM
```

I want to extract the following information from these two:

```
Sydney
London
```

I started using RIGHT, SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX but couldn't get the pattern correct from the right splitting it up essentially via the 'OU=' from the right. Looks messy and can't see an elegant way of splitting strings as you could in C#. - SQL 2014.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Split String function in SQL to split your astring to array and then accessing row with 'OU=' substring. syntax for that is as followed

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet.', ',');
```

or can use method described here

[Split data in sql with multiple delimiters ( , and - ) with owns rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476475/split-data-in-sql-with-multiple-delimiters-and-with-owns-rule)

and

https://raresql.com/2013/01/10/sql-server-split-string-into-rows-based-on-multiple-delimiters/

Comment: what about OU= how would he split it down?

Comment: humm!!! Substring will work here or can use stringsplit again and get the second row

Comment: maybe i don't have sql 2014 then, it must be 2012, there's no STRING_SPLIT function sadly

Comment: provided 2 links which will be helpful in this scenerio

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the next to last instance of `OU=`. Here's how you can do that.

```
declare @table table (c1 varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('CN=ABCDEFG,OU=7SOE,OU=TEMP,OU=Sydney,OU=Australia,DC=LDAP,DC=COM'),
('CN=ABCDEFGHIJ,OU=7SOEFHU,OU=TEST,OU=TEMP,OU=London,OU=Europe,DC=LDAP,DC=COM')


select 
    right(left(c1, len(c1) - charindex('UO',reverse(c1)) - 2),charindex('UO',reverse(left(c1, len(c1) - charindex('UO',reverse(c1)) - 2))) - 2)
from @table
```

Just replace `c1` and `@table` with your column name and table name, respectively.

If you want a slick way to split stuff, here is a function that will do that which is extremely fast, thanks to [Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;

GO
```

Here is how you could use it in your situation:

```
select 
    t.c1
    ,x.ItemNumber                   --this represents the item number in the string.
    ,x.Item                         --this is the value of that item
    ,RN = row_number() over (partition by c1 order by x.ItemNumber desc)
from 
    @table t
    cross apply
    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(c1,',') x
--where
--  left(x.Item,2) = 'OU'           --uncomment this out to see how the RN will be used in the CTE below
order by
    t.c1, 
    x.ItemNumber
```

So, to only get the results you want, we would apply a `row_number()` only to those items which begin with `OU` and order them decending. Thus, the row_number() that = 2 (next to last) would be the value you want.

```
;with cte as(
select 
    *
    ,RN = row_number() over (partition by c1 order by x.ItemNumber desc)
from 
    @table
    cross apply
    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(c1,',') x
where
    left(x.Item,2) = 'OU')

select
    c1,
    YourExtract = right(Item,len(Item) - 3)
from
    cte
where
    RN = 2
```